# FormControl:setValue don't fire input event

Tags: angular, events, angular2-formbuilder

I have a form with a `notes` field bounded by a textarea.

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({});
this.form.addControl('notes', new FormControl(''));
```

The template have an `autoresize` directive attached.

```
<textarea formControlName="notes" autosize></textarea>
```

Such a directive resizes the height of the textarea every time the user change its content.

```
@HostListener('input')
public onChange(textArea: HTMLTextAreaElement): void {
    const textarea = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('textarea');
    this.renderer.setStyle(textarea, 'overflow', 'hidden');
    this.renderer.setStyle(textarea, 'height', 'auto');
    this.renderer.setStyle(textarea, 'height', `${textarea.scrollHeight}px`);
  }
```

However, when I programmatically change the value of the FormControl, the `input` event is not fired, and the textarea is not resized accordingly.

```
this.form.controls['notes'].setValue('a new value'); // not firing events
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `input` you can bind to `ngModelChange` that will be triggered on both events:

```
@HostListener('ngModelChange') onNgModelChange() {
  console.log('ngModelChange');
}
```

See demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-template-say51l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautosize.directive.ts

Answer (score 0):

After a quick glance you misspelled autoresize, in your case it is autosize:

```
<textarea formControlName="notes" autosize></textarea>
```

Comment: While it may be grammatically incorrect, that's the name of the directive. It's worth nothing that the resizing works well when the user input something. The problem occurs only when I change the value programmatically.